# Neo4j: Optimizing `WHERE` on relationship property

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

Here is a query that I run:

```
match (n:User), 
(n) -[r]-> (p:Platform {id:"apple"}),
(n) -[l]-> (lang:Language {id: "en"}),
(n) -[photos:REL]-> (:Event {type: "photo_upload"})
return * LIMIT 30
```

This runs pretty quickly(30-40ms) with Scheme indexes. But the following slows down quite a bit(>1000ms):

```
match (n:User), 
(n) -[r]-> (p:Platform {id:"apple"}),
(n) -[l]-> (lang:Language {id: "en"}),
(n) -[photos:REL]-> (:Event {type: "photo_upload"})
WHERE photos.count > 10
return * LIMIT 30
```

There are only 3000 nodes matching the *first* query but adding `WHERE` slows it down to 1 second. I know we don't have relationship property indexes but even then, naively looping through 3000 nodes wouldn't take 1 second, so I guessing I am doing something wrong, as it doesn't seem to be running the `WHERE` on the matched nodes but runs before matching. How can I optimize this?

PROFILE plan for the first query: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/USQFl.jpg

PROFILE plan for the second one: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RPQH.jpg

EDIT: Further investigation:

When I put `SKIP`, it slows down a lot. So it seems to not filter the matches on each path but matches all separately and then merges, which slows it down. Is there a way to make it match only on the results

Comment: Have you tried executing your query with PROFILE? Can you add in the query plan returned by the profiled query to your description (expanding all elements of the plan first)?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Updated

Comment: To be clear, is the DB exactly the when executing the 2 queries?

Comment: Do you really need the relationships and nodes for the :Platform and :Language, or do you just want those to be predicates to filter the :Users returned?

Comment: @InverseFalcon i jusr want them to be filtered. This kind of query will be standard for me and each relationship might have an additional filter in WHERE

Comment: @cybersam Sorry, didn't understand your question

Comment: @khajvah Was anything added/deleted/updated between the times you performed the 2 queries?

Comment: @cybersam No. I have made some modifications and it runs faster now. I added `MATCH`es on each other node (Platform, Language, Event) before matching the relationships and it runs faster now (200-300ms). Still, the results aren't very impressive, as I have only 6 million nodes right now but am planning to have a few hundred millions.

Comment: @cybersam Does Cypher match everything and then merge or match on previously filtered results?

Comment: Cypher generally does things in the order that you specify in your Cypher code, so it mainly depends on your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you observed that matching first on the specific `Platform`, `Language`, and `Event` nodes sped things up. That is because that helped to focus the search on just the paths relevant to those specific nodes. The Cypher planner is not always sophisticated enough to figure out the most efficient plan, so sometimes you have to help it out.

The following query should be efficient if you have created an index (or uniqueness constraint) on `:Platform(id)`, `:Language(id)`, and `:Event(type)`.

```
MATCH (p:Platform {id:"apple"}), (lang:Language {id: "en"}), (e:Event {type: "photo_upload"})
USING INDEX p:Platform(id)
USING INDEX lang:Language(id)
USING INDEX e:Event(type)
MATCH (n:User)-[r]->(p), (n)-[l]->(lang), (n)-[photos:REL]->(e)
WHERE photos.count > 10
RETURN *
LIMIT 30
```

Notice that I had to give 3 separate hints to the Cypher planner to use the 3 indexes (or uniqueness constraints), as the planner seems to prefer to use at most one index on its own. You should get the fastest results if you use all 3 indexes to quickly get the 3 nodes to start searching from.